# Xpages strange number field value

Tags: xpages

The next inputText is from a repeat control ( having the `indexVar = index` )

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{viewScope.fields[index]}">
                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertNumber type="number" locale="ro"
                        maxFractionDigits="2">

                    </xp:convertNumber>
                </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

Let's say `inputText1=55.556,78`.

I have a save button which pass the value from viewScope to a dataSource field:

```
document1.replaceItemValue("RepeatFields", viewScope.fields.join('#')+'#');
```

Don't bother about the .join functions. I use it to concatenate / delimitate values.

And after I reopend the document: `inputText1=55556.78`. So the `<xp:this.converter>` property is not respected anymore ... `,` isn't anymore the decimal separator as I would like.

How can I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you feed your reapeat control with the splitted value of your prior concatenated number list. What you'll get then isn't numbers but strings in each loop so you should cast your

```
viewScope.fields[index]
```

to a number again.

Comment: Maybe just @TextToNumber()

Comment: You did not cast the right value, see what I wrote before. Do a @TextToNumber(viewScope.fields[index])

Comment: I tried: value="#{@TextToNumber(viewScope.fields[index])}"  , but I get an error.

Comment: Should be (it is no EL anymore): value="#{javascript:@TextToNumber(viewScope.fields[index])}"

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth I already tried : value="#{javascript:@TextToNumber(viewScope.fields[index])}" , but then when I compose the document the default value for the field is set to 0.